# Time not sorted properly KendoUI Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having an issue in sorting the dateTime for my kendoUI grid, see as [my grid snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvRY7.png), the date is sorted correctly (sorted from most recent dateTime), but the **time** is not, where "**Jul/08/2016 15:04:22**" should be on the top (showed in my snapshot), could any one help with this, thank you!

My code:

```
self.gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  sort: { field: "start_time", dir: "asc" },
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {            
          start_time: { type: "date" },      
      }
    }
  }
});

self.myGrid = {
  selectable: true,
  resizable: true,
  sortable: true, // todo: fix sorting issue
  dataSource: self.gridDataSource,
  filterable: true,
  columns: {
        field: "start_time",
        title: "Start Time",
        width: "180px",
        filterable: false,
        template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(start_time), 'MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') #",
        attributes: { style: "text-align: center; " },
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"

  }
}
```

Comment: What is you change format to this `format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, I think I have to create a sorting algorithm for it

Answer (score 0):

Changing you date format to `"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"`.

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pz66rsb0/3/)